# AWS Glue schema registry AVRO multiple events of specific record type in same topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, avro, aws-glue

Hi we are trying to have multiple events on same topic. We have used custom naming strategy to generate different schemas for same topic. However on consumer end it fails to deserialise the schema if the avro file is not on consumer. Now we have to add all the avro schemas for different event types even though consumer is concerned with only one event type (avro schema). We want to avoid this situation and wondering what will be the optimised way to achieve this.

if we only add the concerned schema i.e not add all event type schemas for same topic we get this exception.

````bash
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:194)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:112)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1598)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1210)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition bazaar_identity_user-0
at offset 2505. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.\nCaused by: com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.exception.AWSSchemaRegistryException: Exception occurred while de-serializing Avro message
at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.avro.AvroDeserializer.deserialize(AvroDeserializer.java:103)
at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.GlueSchemaRegistryDeserializationFacade.deserialize(GlueSchemaRegistryDeserializationFacade.java:172)
at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer.deserializeByHeaderVersionByte(GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer.java:160)
at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer.deserialize(GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer.java:116)
at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1387)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:133)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1618)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1454)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:687)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:638)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1272)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1233)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1206)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1410)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1249)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1161)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\nCaused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2051)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4935)
at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.avro.AvroDeserializer.deserialize(AvroDeserializer.java:93)\n\t... 19 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null\n```
````

Comment: Please share your consumer properties

Comment: Use an `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` to cause the unwanted records to be discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure an `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` with your current deserializer as its delegate.

Exceptions will go straight to the error handler and be discarded, by default.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer

> When a deserializer fails to deserialize a message, Spring has no way to handle the problem, because it occurs before the poll() returns. To solve this problem, the ErrorHandlingDeserializer has been introduced. This deserializer delegates to a real deserializer (key or value). If the delegate fails to deserialize the record content, the ErrorHandlingDeserializer returns a null value and a DeserializationException in a header that contains the cause and the raw bytes. When you use a record-level MessageListener, if the ConsumerRecord contains a DeserializationException header for either the key or value, the container’s ErrorHandler is called with the failed ConsumerRecord. The record is not passed to the listener.

Comment: +1 ErrorHandlingDeserializer and set the Logging error handler on container factory of kafka using factory.setErrorHandler(// error handler class )